# Unable to save RSA Key in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have my user defined class with some Encryption written on it. Taken the .jar file of the same.

Class: Test2

```
public static PublicKey getKey(String final_key) {
    try{
        byte[] byteKey = Base64.decode(key.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        X509EncodedKeySpec X509publicKey = new X509EncodedKeySpec(byteKey);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        Key k=kf.generatePublic(X509publicKey);
        return (PublicKey) k;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
}
```

Main Class:

```
String public_key1="MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAzIhoSZkc7jyTXifjc2xNeZwZdlDWjX/t3zrLT6+mUlWOxVmS4CHNiGSQ5crJBG1TkWAwTPgjT5mbCvhkzSm8eTHsRciDLfgDx5GJL7dPTtIudwyv+CoyPUq02myuCAwnSwJLHDXO5bqKDZLv5yCA0IkpkMY/NDO71gt2RUNlhKy1Qd/BG+2nVRPl/hvTLnwkAX+0jGgE3NYqjdrI94K4sZBpZA+zjNdKt7r6wEg6cdxye4JDhgrJVtXcIvReNDZscK3OXSpK1w05cJ/iX+9gDY/l+jS4K6LZ3j9rND+Z6uyBd14qtgg34C3ftckNpPQgosp8f+VRb8oXVg8woWjwKwIDAQAB";
    String newKey=public_key1.replaceAll("\\\n", "");
    System.out.println(newKey);
    Key k=getKey(public_key1);
    System.out.println(k);
    System.out.println("After Encryption:" +encrypt(card1,k));
```

Jmeter Code:

```
import com.pack.testing.Test2;

String Original_String= ctx.getPreviousResult().getResponseDataAsString();
String Trim1=Original_String.substring(0, Original_String.lastIndexOf(","));
String Trim2=Trim1.replaceFirst("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
String Trim3=Trim2.replaceFirst("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
String[] parts = Trim3.split(":");
String myString = parts[1].substring(1, parts[1].length()-1);
String final_string=myString.replaceAll("\\\\n", "");
vars.putObject("publicKey", Test2.getKey(final_string));
log.info(publicKey);
```

In the Main class , i have strings hardcoded. But in reality , that string is changeable through jmeter and i need to pass this string (received from Jmeter) into that encryption class to get the Key as output in Jmeter .

Comment: hmm so what is the question? what is failing?

Comment: How can we save the RSA Key in Jmeter  @Kiril S?