# How can we write some encryption methods in Jmeter using Bean shell Sampler?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

I need some tips of how can we write some Java code in Jmeter using Bean shell Sampler to accomplish Encryption . Help on this highly useful!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [JMeter 4 new features](http://jmeter.apache.org/changes.html) you can use a new function [_digest](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__digest) to encrypt using the following algorithms:

1. MD2
2. MD5
3. SHA-1
4. SHA-224
5. SHA-256
6. SHA-384
7. SHA-512

for example:

```
${__digest(SHA-256,Felix qui potuit rerum cognoscere causas,mysalt,,)}
```

Comment: Thanks @user7294900 . Can we not accomplish RSA algorithm in Jmeter ?

Comment: Thanks @user7294900 . I was using that page only. However, i am getting error in Jmeter while doing the same . Moreover i am using android.util.Base64 package to accomplish the same. But not succeded :(

Comment: Please ask a new question with all the relevant/specific details

Comment: I have already asked in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941915/unable-to-save-rsa-key-in-jmeter. But no response yet :(

Comment: you wrote "Unable to get the public key using jmeter from the custom class" it has no usable details, full error, ...

Comment: Have updated that ticket @user7294900. Could you please provide me a solution?